# COM Component freeze

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, com

I want to build a simple project in *winforms*, playing video.

I try to add a component by following this [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564585(v=vs.85).aspx), when I try to click tab `COM Component` my pc freezes and after a while Visual Studio restarts. It keeps restarting whenever I try to click `COM component`.

I don't know why this happening.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 with Xamarin in it.
[image]

**UPDATE**
when click debug it give me this

[image]

after that i choose the 2017, and click yes. It give me this
[image]

Comment: It's impossible to know what's happening without doing some diagnostics. Start Visual Studio from Visual Studio Command Prompt and enable loging to see if the error's details shows in it. Devenv /log "Path\NameOfLogFile"

Comment: Have you updated Visual Studio to latest patch? It seems a problem with VS itself..

Comment: i have updated. still can't